# Forgot username and password to Ubuntu

Tags: boot, recovery-mode, password-recovery, username

I have an M1 Macbook and used UTM to create an Ubuntu VM. I have now forgotten my username and password for the VM and do not see a recovery boot option in the GNU GRUB menu:

[image: boot menu]

How can I recover or reset the username and password?

Answer (score 2):

Use the try option and mount the disks it shows. Your main volume (/1 of the volumes) will have a /home and your username.

You can then use the password on the system disk to reset it using

```
passwd {username}
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm a newbie and don't know how to do it. I hover the first option "Try or Install Ubuntu" and pressed e. Then it shows the following:

***
setparams 'Try or Install Ubuntu'
    set gfxpayload=keep
    linux    /casper/vmlinuz quiet ---
    initrd    /casper/initrd
***

How do I mount the disk and enter the command? Thank you for your help.